# PHP websocket using socket_recv() - will I ever receive a partial frame?

Tags: php, sockets, websocket

I am writing a websocket server in PHP (using the `sockets` extension) and I need a bit of help understanding to what extent I need to deal with fragmented messages.

My understanding of how websocket information is passed is as follows:

1. Client application sends a `MESSAGE` (of arbitrary length) to the client-side API.
2. Client-side API splits the `MESSAGE` into one or more `FRAMES` (also of arbitrary length) and sends them to the network layer.
3. The network layer splits the data into a number of `PACKETS` to be sent over the network via TCP.
4. The server receives the TCP `PACKETS` (possibly out-of-order, but it re-orders them if necessary) and delivers them to the application that is listening on the relevant port.
5. The application calls `socket_recv()` to read the received data from the socket.

The thing I want to understand is **what data that my application will see when reading a stream of websocket data using `socket_recv()`?**

Specifically, to what extent do I need to worry about the fragmentation?

---

To help explain my question, here is the above process in diagrammatic form:

```
1. Web app  (messages):   [Message_1][Message_2]
2. Browser  (frames)  :   [Messag][e_1][Messag][e_2]
3. TCP send (packets) :   [Mess][ag][e_1][Mess][ag][e_2]
4. TCP recv (packets) :   [ag][Mess][e_2][ag][Mess][e-1]
5. socket_recv        :   ???
```

If I call `socket_recv()` in a loop, until it returns a length of zero (adding to my internal buffer each time), am I guaranteed to get a single, complete `MESSAGE`?

```
socketrecv: [Message_1]
socketrecv: [Message_2]
```

Or a single complete `FRAME`?

```
socketrecv: [Messag]
socketrecv: [e_1]
socketrecv: [Messag]
socketrecv: [e_2]
```

Or, will it actually be an arbitrary series of `PACKETS` representing whatever data has been received so far (which may therefore be a partial `FRAME` or even multiple `FRAMES`)?

```
socketrecv: [Messag
socketrecv: e_1][Mess
socketrecv:
socketrecv: ag
socketrecv: e_2]
```

Or something else?

I am quite happy stitching together the various `FRAMES` of data, but it will make things a lot easier if I can assume the first bytes of received data in each poll (instigated using `socket_select()`) will always be the `FRAME` header, rather than having to handle it as a raw byte stream which needs to be stitched back into `FRAMES` before we begin.

Comment: Have you get a response to your question ? I'm interested in such an explaination but can't find any relevant information :/

Comment: Nope - not yet.  My implementation assumes that the frames appear in the order they were sent, but that any read from the socket may contain an arbitrary slice of this data.  I therefore have two buffers: the stream buffer, containing the raw bytes read from the socket, and the frame buffer, which contains complete frames once they have been fully received.  No idea whether this is required or just massive overkill, but in the absence of an answer it's the safest approach, and it seems to work well.

Comment: Thanks for your response, i will try something similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh well, I used to websockets in my C++ code and yes it can be fragmented due how the TCP protocol works.

There are two types of datastream for websocket: Hixie (Old), Hybi (New) and also there are versions, hybi-13 .. hybi-17 for example.

But does not matter, because your problem is socket_recv() only retrieves data from buffer, buffer is depend on your network settings (MTU) and operating system and hardware... so complex.. 1-byte read is even possible as much as 16MB too.

So if you would like to implement websocket in PHP, you have to read and parse a frame and get its size, if size is available you cut and process then continue, if not read more.

It is very possible to receive incomplete frame or one frame and an incomplete next one.
So you have to step over and find begining of the frame calculate it's size and step forward if you have remaining data you have to reserve in a buffer aka variable and next reading must be append after.

But first, you have to read at least 4 bytes for first. (Header Size)
Good to know hybi protocol uses "compression" so crafeul with payload the frame bytes can be vary depending on it's integer type.

See the C code below.

```
        payload_length = frame[1] & 0x7f;
        if (payload_length < 126) 
        {
            hdr_length = 2;
            payload_length = payload_length; // FYI / DUMMY
        } 
        else if (payload_length == 126) 
        {
            payload_length = (frame[2] << 8) + frame[3];
            hdr_length = 4;
        } 
        else 
             ....
```

Comment: This answer covers the question I was trying to ask, i.e. what data does the application see when reading from the raw socket. It backs-up my gut feeling that what we would get is broadly the second example in my question, i.e. we would get each websocket message in the order they were sent, but not necessarily as individual messages - effectively as if all the messages were concatenated into one long binary string and then arbitrarily sliced into different sized chunks.  It validates my approach (which I worried was over-engineered) which is written to take this into account. Bounty awarded!

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty good at networking and I've written a lot of Twisted networking code in my day (network sockets library in Python)

I have the book "Unix Network Programming 3rd Edition" at home and I took a peek to see what it said... I bought this book some years ago used from a library because it is said to be the "authority" on the TCP/IP stack and its specifications.

### From Chapter 2 "The Transport Layer"

The smallest `MTU` in the path between two hosts is called the **path MTU**. Today the Ethernet MTU is 1,500 bytes and is often the path MTU.
...
When an IP datagram is to be sent out an interface, if the size of the datagram exceeds the link MTU, fragmentation is performed by the IPV4/IPV6 stack. The fragments are not normally reassembled until they reach the final destination. On IPv4 both hosts and routers can perform fragmentation. On IPv6 only hosts can perform fragmentation.
...
IPv4 and IPv6 define a minimum reassembly buffer size, the minimum datagram size that we are guaranteed any implementation must support. For IPv4 this is **576 bytes**.

### The Application

Any application or IPv4 host stack is guaranteed to always receive `link MTU` sized *datagrams* **at the application level**, ie `socket_recv`

Your application may receive smaller amounts of data, because less data may be sent and this is why socket servers have ways of knowing when a message has ended, and a new one is beginning.

**Typical Socket Server**

```c
ssize_t numBytesRcvd = recv(clntSocket, buffer, BUFSIZE, 0)
if (numBytesRcvd < 0 ) // 0 indicates end of stream
    exit(1);
```

In the snippet above, the process receives at MOST `BUFSIZE` bytes from the operating system. This doesn't mean it won't receive less, or the other side of the connection didn't send less.

The whole discussion of what happens at lower levels of the stack is actually meaningless to your purposes.

When you call `socket_recv` in PHP it's doing the same thing, here's the source code:

```c
    if ((retval = recv(php_sock->bsd_socket, ZSTR_VAL(recv_buf), len, flags)) < 1) {
        zend_string_efree(recv_buf);
        ZEND_TRY_ASSIGN_REF_NULL(buf);
    } else {
        ZSTR_LEN(recv_buf) = retval;
        ZSTR_VAL(recv_buf)[ZSTR_LEN(recv_buf)] = '\0';
        ZEND_TRY_ASSIGN_REF_NEW_STR(buf, recv_buf);
    }
```

You can see it too also tries to receive `len` bytes.
It then adds these bytes to `recv_buf` using the function `ZEND_TRY_ASSIGN_REF_NEW_STR` and adds a null value at the end to terminate the received string.

## The real Answer

Any sockets application needs a way to distinguish length and structure of a **message**.
The message size may be arbitrary and the message itself may be arbitrary based on your requirements.
This is why `protocols` exist. Protocols are just specifications of sizes and arrangements of bytes.

In your case you want to send a message from a client and receive it at the server and know when it's the end of the message and then possibly repeat that loop indefinitely.

What you are actually asking is:

**How do I construct a specification for the structure of a datagram and know when the datagram has ended** - You need a protocol!

This is the basics of how the simplest of protocols works:

1. Define a fixed size `header` this header will by a number of bytes that tells you how long the message is. Put any meta information in the header.
   The important part is that the `length` of the header is **fixed**. We'll call this header length `HEADER_LEN`
2. When receiving a message, construct a buffer, keep writing to that buffer until you've received at least `HEADER_LEN`.
3. Split the string into `header`, `extra` where `header` is the header bytes you received and `extra` are additional bytes you received while consuming the header bytes.
4. Parse the `header` using PHP's `unpack` function. It's capable of parsing BINARY/C integers.
   Let's say you've defined `HEADER_LEN` to be **5 bytes** = `[4 BYTE INT + NULL]`.
   Parse the header `4 byte int` into **body_length** variable - this will be an integer telling us how long your body is.
   This design assumes that the CLIENT constructed a properly composed header of at least 5 bytes according to our specification.
   ...
   If it didn't, we have another mess of issues to deal with. Namely, throwing away the malformed message and finding the next well-formed message.
   Unfortunately an error-correction conversation would get long for this post.
5. Read an additional `body_length` bytes from the socket.  This includes `extra` bytes we've already received.
6. You've now received the entire datagram
7. Wait for the next datagram, repeat.

## How to accomplish this in real life

The above was an interesting academic exercise to help us understand how TCP socket clients and servers work - but it's not the easiest to build our own application on top of it.

Fortunately others have done the work for us.

[Wamp](https://wamp-proto.org) is protocol designed for websockets that makes it easy to define message formats and ensure they are reliably sent/received.

The PHP implementation of Wamp is called [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/docs/wamp)

These tools would be highly preferable versus rolling your own protocol, as they handle malformed messages and error recovery on their own.

Good Luck!

Comment: This is a very detailed and thorough about the TCP stack, which broadly describes what is already covered by my diagram in the question.  However, it doesn't answer the fundamental question about "what next", i.e. when the application is looking at the buffer, filled from the TCP layer, will it be getting individual messages or arbitrary chunks of (correctly ordered) data.  An interesting answer, but incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

It's fully documented on the internet... TCP is **reliable** and connection-oriented.

You receive the message complete and in correct order - or never. Each segment of a message must be acknowlegded by the receiver and if that is not done, the fragment is sent again (for a couple of times...). Re-assembling of the message is done by the TCP stack, so you don't have to worry about packet order or missing packets in an applicatin... either you get the full message or an error.

Don't misunderstand the buffers... when you call socket_recv(), you'll provide a buffer, but this is not the same buffer the underlying TCP-stack is using.

UDP is the counter part, where you'd have to pay attention to all the details. You get datagrams potentially in wrong order, multiple times, corrupted/incomplete or otherwise defective... or even never! Means: you might end up with a sequence that contains gaps, and you'll have to live with it.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by 'the message' in your second paragraph.  Do you mean that each `socket_recv()` call (assuming enough buffer space is provided) will give me exactly one or zero websocket messages, or are you using a different meaning of `message` to the one given in the question?  Your answer implies my first example is correct, but it would be good if this were explicit.

Comment: TCP is reliable, but TCP is also stream-oriented, not datagram-oriented. You're guaranteed by TCP that the messages constituting the stream are in the right order, so you can read it as a stream, but application-level framing (such as OP's websocket question) is a different beast.

Comment: I think this response is answering the wrong question - this wasn't so much about how the TCP layer works but about what comes out of `socket_recv()`, i.e. how far up the stack are we.  I also think you are using a different meaning of 'message' to the question, which is a bit confusing.